# How can I store a JavaScript variable in local storage?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a JavaScript variable called `addNumber` which just adds a number by 1 to a div any time I click a button. But I'm using it on a website which has multiple pages, and every time I change pages, it resets the counter. I've used `console.log()` to check the variable multiple times, and it always resets back to zero any time I leave the page, even when I keep the tab open. This counter is kept at the top of the page for all to see, and I want it kept there in a navbar, kind of like the shopping cart on Amazon. Is there a way I can do something like that using only vanilla JavaScript?

Thank you.

Comment: ajax and a database. `localStorage` is not suitable if you want everybody to see this count

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Please clarify `"This counter is kept at the top of the page for all to see"` - also, is it just you that can `click the button` or does this apply to all users? If it is all users do they update a single value or a variable relevant to themselves only?

Answer (score 1):

You may find this link helpfull.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Quick answer you store key value pairs using a string tag to identify them:

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
localStorage.getItem("lastname"); //this returns the string "Smith"
```

Edit: i do not recommend you doing this in a production enviroment. You should stick to the framework of the project. If the project has no framework or is just for school or learning purposes then i guess is a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a variable in localStorage to access it somewhere else through

Try using:

```js
function onClickevent(){
    addNumber = addNumber +1 
    localStorage.setItem('counter', addNumber);
}
```

Then get it through

```js
//Just assign it to your div 
const getIt = localStorage.getItem('counter')
```

Here is some documentation on LocalStorage and how to use it :)
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_getitem.asp

[https://blog.logrocket.com/localstorage-javascript-complete-guide/#:~:text=To%20get%20items%20from%20localStorage%2C%20use%20the%20getItem()%20method,in%20the%20browser's%20localStorage%20object.](https://%20https://blog.logrocket.com/localstorage-javascript-complete-guide/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20items%20from%20localStorage%2C%20use%20the%20getItem()%20method,in%20the%20browser%27s%20localStorage%20object.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution you can try is :

In the .js file at the end of all lines, type

```
window.localstorage.setItem("addNumber",addNumber);
```

The addNumber will be stored with an ID of addNumber.

To later retrieve, use :

```
window.localstorage.getItem("addNumber");
```

You may assign the above to a variable like

var number =....

Then console the number.

I hope this helps.